# Why do I need to press CTRL+D twice to break out of `while ((c=getchar())!=EOF)` in Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: c, ubuntu, terminal, eof, getchar

I am new to C Programming and Ubuntu. I was reading the "The C Programming Language" by D.M Ritchie where I found the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    int nc=0;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        nc++;
    }

    printf("%d Characters \n",nc);

    return 0;
}
```

But while running the program I enter "Hello" ,then <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd> *twice* to get the actual number of characters which is 5.

But when I enter "Hello" then <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd> *once*, nothing happens, the terminal still waits for input.

Why?

Comment: I think that CTRL+D sends `EOF` if there isn't any data to be flushed into the `stdin`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746522/why-is-some-code-from-kr-not-working-in-codeblocks/29746577#comment47630286_29746577

Comment: @CoolGuy  I followed the above link and found the comment of Veritas to be helpful. Thanks for your help. But if I press "ENTER" after "Hello" and then CTRL+D once , the character count becomes 6. I think it takes "\n" to be an extra character in addition to 'Hello'. Isn't ?

Comment: Yes. That's right. Remember that `EOF != '\n'`. So the loop won't break when you press the enter key.

Comment: I now tried the following code ....                                                                                                              #include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char c;
  c=getchar();
  while (c!= EOF)
   {
     putchar(c);
     c=getchar();
   }
  return 0;
}
The above code shows the input as output... Here when I press "ENTER" the loop breaks after showing the output as expected.. When EOF!= "\n" How this happens? Here I don't have to press CTRL+D at all!!

Comment: @SoumyadeepGanguly , `c` should be an `int`. I suggest you post a new question if you have any.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [@Veritas's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746522/why-is-some-code-from-kr-not-working-in-codeblocks/29746577#comment47630286_29746577),

> On linux Ctrl-D only works when the buffer is already empty otherwise it just flushes it. Therefore unless he has pressed enter without any characters after that, he will have to press Ctrl-D twice.

This explains the issue. You have to press it twice because you , after typing `Hello`, did not press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> to flush the input into the `stdin`. So the first time you press <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd>, it flushes the data into the `stdin`. The second time you press it, `EOF` is sent.